# При длительных нагрузках на VPS производительность падает

Tags: linux, ubuntu

ОС Ubuntu 14.04. Вначале все идет хорошо, но минут через 30-40 нагрузка с 95% падает до 11%. Почему это происходит? Как можно стабилизировать скорость вычислений (что бы не падала  производительность)?

Comment: Производительность чего? Похоже на утечку памяти.

Comment: Во время майнинга, например (не люблю, что бы просто так сервер стоял)

Comment: vps где ? своя ? у хостера ? если у хостера, подозреваю что майнинг зарещен, и даже не то что бы майнинг, а есть ограничение на вычислительное время. Если своя, то подробности в вопрос приложите (параметры vps, программа для майнинга, метод и т.п.)

Comment: Согласен с @EvgeniiIzhboldin, есть смысл написать в ТП VPS провайдера. Мне один раз провайдер начал слать грозные предупредления при конвертации видео, он решил что у меня что-то заглюкнуло, раз нагрузка на ЦП так выросла.

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin сервера на амазоне хостятся

Comment: Смотрите ограничение своей конфигурации, не знаю как на амазоне, работал с Azure в основном, но подозреваю что для тяжелых вычислительных задач, нужны специальные конфигурации. На стандартных скорее всего вы упретесь в ограничения.